# Working on the User Profile and Mysite web

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I just trying to get few information from a user (like if the mysite web exits) and working with that.
The main problem is understand if the user has a mysite web and delete it if exists but to do that the only possible way seems using CSOM.
Also I should create a Powershell script for that.
Did anyone never do that?

Comment: Similiar post - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78198/how-to-delete-memberss-personal-sites?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this yet ?

```
 //get userProfile...
 if (userProfile.PersonalSite != null)
     {
         using (SPSite personalSite = userProfile.PersonalSite)
          {
             if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
             {
                   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb web = (SPWeb)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"];

           SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();
                   web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    personalSite.Delete();
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
               }
            }
  } 
}
```

[Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/31b0e7ff-0af1-42a4-93ae-766146a30092/deleting-a-mysite-site-programatically-in-a-web-service-using-c?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

You can do it through Central Admin as well as stated in this post [How to delete a my site for a single user - SharePoint 2013 on premises](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72981/how-to-delete-a-my-site-for-a-single-user-sharepoint-2013-on-premises)

If you really want to use powershell then go through all profiles and find one for the given username and delete it ? e.g.

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added 
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) { 
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" 
} 


$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://skvkfm-it01/");  
$ServiceContext = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($site);  

#Get UserProfileManager from the My Site Host Site context 
$ProfileManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)    
$AllProfiles = $ProfileManager.GetEnumerator()  

foreach($profile in $AllProfiles)  
{  
    $DisplayName = $profile.DisplayName  
    $AccountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value  

    #Do not delete setup (admin) account from user profiles. Please enter the account name below 
    if($AccountName -ne "Domain\MySiteSVApp") 
    { 
        $ProfileManager.RemoveUserProfile($AccountName); 
        write-host "Profile for account ", $AccountName, " has been deleted" 
    } 

}  
write-host "Finished." 
$site.Dispose()
```