# Remove and recreate all personal sites - mysites - remove them from DB without waiting ~25 days

Tags: my-site, database, delete, mysite, cleanup

Is there a easy way to remove (delete) all personal sites and recreate them all over again? I also want to delete them from the sql.

I've tried to delete personal sites and run my site clean up job but it seems not to be removed from the DB. I know I have to wait ~14 days and then ~11 days before they get removed from the DB. **Is there a way to force delete them without waiting?**

The reason I want to delte the db entry is to not get in a situation that the db runs out of space.

The best way would be to recreate the entire web application but I can't do that because of integration to all other systems.

When deleting personal mysites I run this lines..

```
..
foreach($profile in $AllProfiles)
{
    $DisplayName = $profile.DisplayName
    $AccountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value  

    if($profile.PersonalSite -ne $Null)
    {
       $profile.PersonalSite.Delete()
       write-host $AccountName , " personel site deleted successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a my site for a single user - SharePoint 2013 on premises](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72981/how-to-delete-a-my-site-for-a-single-user-sharepoint-2013-on-premises)

Comment: The thread you refers to do not force delete them from the db, without waiting ~25 days

Comment: Why not just compile a list of MySites based on managed path and/or Site Template ID (MYSITE#0, IIRC)? From there, use Remove-SPSite w/o -GradualDelete. You can then go through the UPM OM to clear out the Personal Site URL.

Comment: @TrevorSeward I did almost the same .. and it worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below PS  code for deleting the mysites?

```
 Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

 [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server")
 $mysiteHostUrl = "http://my"
 $mysite = Get-SPSite $mysiteHostUrl
 $context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($mysite)
 $upm =  New-Object    
 Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
 $AllProfiles = $upm.GetEnumerator()
 foreach($profile in $AllProfiles)
 {
 $DisplayName = $profile.DisplayName
  $AccountName = 
      $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.
        PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value  
  if($profile.PersonalSite -ne $Null)
   {
   $profile.PersonalSite.Delete()
   write-host $AccountName , " personal site deleted successfully"
    }
  }
  $mysite.Dispose();
```

Comment: I've got almost the same code .. but this code does not delete the personal site from the db straight away.. you have to wait ~25 days before sharepoint removes the personal site entry from the db

Comment: Manipulating the entry directly from content db is not supported by MSFT. But can you look at the All_Docs table from your web app's content DB with your SS Mgmnt Studio? I hope you would be able to get the row in that table related to mysite.

Comment: Can you check this link also: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/deleting-orphan-mysites

Comment: Through SSMS : http://www.demantprasad.com/2013/09/sql-queries-for-sharepoint-content.html                                                                                   "select  count(*) as 'Total Site Collection' from sites"  . The below sql  can get the web title and you would be able to get the mysite title and delete it from Content DB . "select Title as 'Root Web Title', Sites.RootWebId, Sites.Id as 'Site Collection ID' from webs
 inner join Sites on Webs.Id = Sites.RootWebId" . Hope this helps